# ExtJS Horizontal Scroll bars blocking tab titles in TabPanel

Tags: google-chrome, extjs, extjs4

This is an issue I've had a hard time researching and tracking down. When loading the following panel in a view, scroll bars appear on each tab title (not one long scroll bar for all of the tabs, but individual tab titles). It's not a huge issue for me since I'm on Mountain Lion with small scroll bars, but other users on older OS X versions have the huge blue scroll bars that block the entire tab title.

I'll post a screenshot when I get one, but here's the code:

```
Ext.define('App.view.case.CasePanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    alias : 'widget.case-panel',
    title : 'Edit Case',
    layout: 'fit',
    border: false,
    autoScroll: true,
    constrainHeader: true,

    initComponent: function() {
        this.items = [{
            xtype: 'panel',
            autoScroll: true,
            layout: 'border',
            items: [{
                region: 'west',
                xtype: 'case-edit-case-info',
                split: true,
                border: true,
                width: 300
            },{
                region: 'center',
                xtype: 'tabpanel',
                activeTab: 0,
                autoScroll: true,
                border: false,
                defaults: {border:false, bodyStyle:'padding:5px'},
                items: [{
                    title: 'One',
                    xtype: 'case-edit-tab-one'   // these aren't the actual tab names, but you get the idea.
                },{
                    title: 'Two',
                    xtype: 'case-edit-tab-two'
                },{
                    title: 'Three',
                    xtype: 'case-edit-tab-three'
                },{
                    title: 'Four',
                    xtype: 'case-edit-tab-four'
                },{
                    title: 'Five',
                    xtype: 'case-edit-tab-five'
                },{
                    title: 'Six',
                    xtype: 'case-edit-tab-six'
                },{
                    title: 'Seven',
                    xtype: 'case-edit-tab-seven'
                }]
            }]
        }];

        this.bbar = [{
            text: 'Save',
            action: 'save'
        }, {
            text: 'Cancel',
            action: 'cancel'
        }];

        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

Any ideas as to why it's doing this?

(Mac OS X, latest Chrome version)

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove autoScroll from the first panel:

```
initComponent: function() {
    this.items = [{
        xtype: 'panel',
        autoScroll: true,
        layout: 'border',
        ...
    }]
}
```